# How to see this format hh:mm from hh:mm:ss in SQL Server 2008 query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to see this format `hh:mm` from `hh:mm:ss` in SQL Server 2008 query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct, built-in functionality for this.

Assuming you have a `DATETIME` or `TIME` column in SQL Server, you need to hack it like this:

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), YourDateTimeColumn, 108), 1, 5)
```

The `CONVERT` statement with style = 108 will convert your date to `hh:mm:ss` and then you just chop off the last three characters.

Things like this really shouldn't be done in the database - that's purely presentation logic, and it belongs in the UI app.

Comment: Ridiculous that there is no DATE_FORMAT equivalent... Alas!

Comment: @JD: agree, it's not SQL Server's strong side - then again, SQL Server is about **storing** data - not really about nicely presenting it...